# oAuth2 php Server Library: how to integrate it?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I'm trying to integrate oAuth2 in my website. I'm using the library of bShaffer on GitHub: https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php

I've seen some screencasts about how oAuth2 works and so on, so I know enough things. But what I don't really understand is: how do I pass the username/email or other data about the user?
I mean: my website will be the identity provider and I need to authenticate the user to another website. Now, when the user logs in, how do I pass its username or something other? 
I don't find anything about how to pass data in the oAuth2 Server php documentation. Just found something about how do I pass the userID, but nothing more. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look here. Worth spending $12 to getr the full course! You get a server running the API, a cron connecting to it, and another site connecting to it! And it uses Brent's library https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/oauth/intro

Comment: Thank you. I've seen this (some videos, I guess), and I know how oAuth2 works and so on - I just need to know how, using that library, can pass other parameters like username or email!

Comment: I'm busy going through those vids myself. Tell you next week! ;-)

Comment: I'm sure you can just post what you need to the endpoint. OAuth will deal with the headers it cares about, you'll get the vars you care about in your controller or whatever.

Comment: Yeah, I think so... that's the fact - which method or what should I be using for posting data to the endpoint? 
Anyway, maybe I think I could take the course, I don't know! Will see... but actually my only limit is this.

Comment: I didn't buy it a couple of years ago when it was $50. I snapped it up last week when i saw the price! $12 well spent! Think of the money we could make building all types of API's! :-D all the best amigo!