# how to passively access google apis using google client?

Tags: php, api, oauth, google-api, google-api-php-client

Is it possible to passively access google API using google api php client library? What I want to do is connect to google API by providing necessary credentials (not using oauth).

Basically, my oauth authentication will be in [googleads](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib) php lib and want to access resources using php [client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) lib. Or is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

What I really curious about for hours is integrating those two libraries (GoogleAds PHP Api and Google API Client API). The former uses pure Oauth and the latter uses 'Google_Client' implementation in accessing Google API.

Comment: I would suggest that you check out the google playground

Comment: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: And in my personal opinion make your own client.That way you will learn how everything goes.When you hear the first time of all the scopes grand types etc ... sounds confusing.But after a few days you will manage to solve it.

Comment: Check out the google playground for oauth and see how it works.PS scroll down and find google play console in the list

Comment: thanks for your response. I think google playground does not include adwords

Comment: Check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437988/oauth2-php-server-library-how-to-integrate-it/44444414#44444414

Comment: I'm explaining here how the whole OAuth2.0 server part goes also it will help you to undarstand the client more

Comment: I understand the concepts of Oauth. What I really curious about for hours is integrating those two libraries (GoogleAds PHP Api and Google API Client API). The former uses pure Oauth and the latter uses 'Google_Client' implementation in accessing Google API.

Comment: If you understood the concept totally you would see that there is not problem there.I suggest that you explore more about it make some dummy project....Good luck